# How to use custom listener in android with onStateChange?

Tags: java, android, textview, listener, onchange

I've been trying to implement an onStateChange listener and have looked across the internet for help, but nothing seems to solve my specific case.  My issue is that I'm making a text based adventure, and I need to disallow clicks until the textbox has finished its "typewriter" style printing.  Once it finishes, an arrow image should appear and you should now be able to click the textbox to advance the text.  Unfortunately, since the text appearing character by character appears in the special TextView class, I'm not sure how to use an onStateChange with my active activity(ies), the special TextView class, and the often recommended third class I've seen in examples.  Here is what I have so far:

I've seen many suggestions recommend a class like this:

```
public class TypewriterManager {
private TypewriterListener typewriterListener = null;

public interface TypewriterListener {
    public void onStateChange(boolean state);
}

public void registerListener (TypewriterListener listener) {
    typewriterListener = listener;
}

// -----------------------------
// the part that this class does

private boolean isTypewriterFinished = false;
public void doYourWork() {
    // do things here
    // at some point
    isTypewriterFinished = false;
    // now notify if someone is interested.
    if (typewriterListener != null)
        typewriterListener.onStateChange(isTypewriterFinished);
}
}
```

Now, I imagine I would somehow call the onStateChange in the runnable?

```
public class Typewriter extends TextView {

private CharSequence mText;
private int mIndex;
private long mDelay = 500; //Default 500ms delay


public Typewriter(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Typewriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
        if(mIndex <= mText.length()) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
        }else{
            //call listener?
        }
    }
};

}
```

However, I need to call this listener in my main activities where the Typewriter TextBox physically is, and that's where I'm stumped.  Maybe it's the way my brain is used to Android, but I want something that looks like:

```
typewriter.setOnTypewriterFinishedListener(new View.OnTypewriterFinishedListener)
```

Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Merge this two classes together. You don't need any class like TypeWriterManager unless you are not using it anywhere else. Call the listener same way as you are doing in TypeWriterManager

Comment: If I were to do that, should I implement an interface into Typewriter?  And would doYourWork() be called where I have the comment in runnable?

Comment: You should create the interface in TypeWriter. Implement it wherever you want the status callback. And call the onStatusChanged from your runnable.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'll have to try to implement it tomorrow.  Again, thanks for the help.